# How to update an ImageField in Django model with a new Image

Tags: python, django, django-models

In my project a user can upload an image and once it is saved I can run a `post_save` signal to modify the image using `Pillow`. And after modifying the image I need to replace the existing image with the new image. Now the issue is if I run the save method in the post_save signal it will lead to maximum recursion error.So instead of this I am thinking of using update method but it throws an error regarding the characters in the file.

Below is the code:

```
   def menuImageLocation(instance,filename):
       return "%s/%s"%(instance,filename)   

   class restaurantMenuImage(models.Model):
     restaurant     = models.ForeignKey(restaurantCreateUpdate)
     title      =   models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
     menuImage  = models.ImageField(upload_to=menuImageLocation,null=True,blank=True,verbose_name="Menu Image") 

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.restaurant)      

    @receiver(post_save,sender=restaurantMenuImage)
    def modifyMenuImage(sender,instance,**kwargs):

getRestaurant = restaurantCreateUpdate.objects.get(restaurantName=instance.restaurant)
image_path  = instance.menuImage.path
filename    = os.path.basename(image_path)

image_hold  = Image.open(image_path)

image = image_hold.resize((300,300),Image.ANTIALIAS)

temp_loc = "%s/%s/%s/tmp"%(settings.MEDIA_ROOT,"menu",getRestaurant.uniqueID)

if not os.path.exists(temp_loc):
    os.makedirs(temp_loc)

temp_file_path = os.path.join(temp_loc,filename)    
if os.path.exists(temp_file_path):
    temp_path = os.path.join(temp_loc,"%s" %(random.random()))
    os.makedirs(temp_path)
    temp_file_path = os.path.join(temp_path,filename)

temp_image = open(temp_file_path,"w")           

image.save(temp_image,quality=80)

temp_data = open(temp_file_path,"r")

image_file = File(temp_data)
instance.menuImage.save(filename, image_file)
```

So if I run the last line of the code, this will result into maximum recursion error, and instead of using save method I am trying to use update method the file path but for that I am getting the error that the characters exceed the `max_length` of the "image_file". Will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Before you run the last line, add a check if the image path of the instance is not the same as the new image path. Then the code will only run once. Your problem occurs, because the code in your post_save signal is always run when you call save on your model, which creates an endless loop. So you need to be careful when you call save in your post_save signal method.

Something like this should help:

```
if instance.menuImage != image_file:
    instance.menuImage.save(filename, image_file)
```